# How to add quantity box with add to cart button to variable and simple products on shop page?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

By default Woocommerce doesn't have quantity box for variable products.

I've tried https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-ajax-add-to-cart-for-variable-products/ but it only shows up on single product page.

How to show quantity box on product page?

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own custom quantity-box:

Here is short overview how I did it for my site: (hope I´m able to help you with this)

I removed the standard woocommerce-hooks inside of my themes functions.php

For example:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_price', 10 );
```

Overview for all the woocommerce hooks: (Visual guide)

Archive-Page: https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-visual-hook-guide-archiveshopcat-page/

Single-Product: https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-visual-hook-guide-single-product-page/

After removing the hooks I added them on the desired location with a custom function which contains my custom quantity-box.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'customize_woocommerce_archive_product', 10 );

function customize_woocommerce_archive_product(){
   global $product;
   $id = $product->get_id();
   $permalink = get_permalink( $product->get_id());
   $step = 1;
   $min_value = 1;
   $max_value = 10000;
   $input_name = $id;
   $input_value = 1;
   $input_name = $id;
   $sku = $product->get_sku();

   <input id="quantity_counter<?php echo $id;?>" 
   type="number" step="<?php echo esc_attr( $step ); ?>" 
   min="<?php echo esc_attr( $min_value ); ?>" 
   max="<?php echo esc_attr( $max_value ); ?>" 
   name="<?php echo esc_attr( $input_name ); ?>" 
   value="<?php echo esc_attr( $input_value ); ?>" 
   title="<?php echo esc_attr_x( 'Qty', 'Product quantity input tooltip', 'woocommerce' ) ?>" 
   class="input-text qty text custom_quantity" size="4"/>

   <div class="custom_pricing_table_row custom_pricing_table_button_container">

        <a href="<?php echo $permalink;?>/?add-to-cart=<?php echo $id; ?>" 
        name="<?php echo $id;?>" data-quantity="1" 
        class="custom_pricing_table_button button product_type_simple 
        add_to_cart_button ajax_add_to_cart quantity_trigger" 
        data-product_id="<?php echo $id;?>" 
        data-product_sku="<?php echo $sku;?>" rel="nofollow">Add to cart</a>

   </div>
}
```

Now you have to add some javascript to change the value of data-quantity.

Inside my themes function.js I created the following function:

```
 jQuery('.quantity_trigger').click(function(){
    var clickedTrigger_ID = jQuery(this).attr('name');  
    var searchID = 'quantity_counter' + clickedTrigger_ID;

    var currentCounter = document.getElementById(searchID);
    var quantity = currentCounter.value;

    jQuery(this).attr("data-quantity",quantity);

});
```

Hope this code is able to help you out.